# How to pass an object from controller to view with sessions?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass an instance of `Alerter` class from my controller to a view with session. 
 Is this even possible and if, how can i implement it?

At the moment, I'm getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Alerter" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<?php

use Acme\Repositories\Authority\Session\SessionInterface;

class Alerter {

    protected $type;
    protected $message;

    function __construct($message, $type = 'warning')
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

}

/**
 * Class SessionsController
 */
class SessionsController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * @var Acme\Repositories\Authority\Session\SessionInterface
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * Inject SentrySession Dependency.
     *
     * @param SessionInterface $session
     */
    function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Logout the user.
     *
     * @return \Acme\Repositories\Authority\Session\Response
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->destroy();

        $alerter = new Alerter('Hello', 'success');

        return Redirect::to('login')->with('alert', $alerter);
    }

}
```

And my view looks like this:

```
@if (Session::has('alert'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        {{ Session::get('alert')->getMessage() }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There seem to be some issues regarding deserialization. This strikes me as something you shouldn't be doing with sessions. Keep in mind that sessions need to be serializable (they're stored as strings).

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right, but it worth a try :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Alerter` class isn't loaded when you try to access an instance of it from the session, so the deserialization obviously fails and even tells us that we should load it first :

> Please ensure that the class definition "Alerter" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

You can try modifying `composer.json` and adding your class to the `autoload` section - add this just after the `classmap` section :

```
"psr-0": {
    "CustomNamespace": "path/to/where/your/controller/is"
}
```

*(replace the path with the actual path to the controller file's directory)*

Then add that namespace at the top of your controller's file :

```
namespace CustomNamespace;
```

Finally, run `composer dump-autoload` try it again, it should work correctly now.